# How to Convert the Decimal Round off from the least precision Decimal value

Tags: java, rounding

I have the Case to round a Value with more the 2 digit Precision I like to consider the precision from least decimal Avail

**for eg:)** if A = 120.1453654 (Before Rounding Off)

Rounding Off Process to happen as follows 
A = 120.145365   (Round off the 4 value with no change)
A = 120.14537    (Round off the 5 value)
A = 120.1454    (Round off the 7 value)
A = 120.145    (Round off the 4 value with no change)
A = 120.15    (Round off the 5 value)
A = 120.15    (Round off the 5 value)

So finally my output will as **120.15**

Comment: So fringe case is that `1.234444` rounds to `1.23`, while `1.234445` rounds to `1.24`? `1.234445` → `1.23445` → `1.2345` → `1.235` → `1.24`?

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

you could potentially convert it to a BigDecimal; set the rounding method and set the precision then output it to a different type if need. or you could checkout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: It only getting round off 1 digit to  precision decimal I need to get round off from the least digit( that is last digit 9)  which gives 1.235 again when I round it of it gives 1.24

Comment: if you are wanting to take into account all of the decimal points (you aren't really rounding at this point); convert the number to a string, loop thru each digit starting at the end of the string, if the number is > 5 round it up to 0, carry the 1 into the next and repeat

Comment: not that i'm aware of. rounding usually only takes into account the precision + 1 digit. that 1 digit will tell you whether or not the number should be rounded up. since you are wanting to take into account ALL of the digits i don't know of another way

Comment: potentially you could set the precision to 5, then set it again to 4, then 3... that MIGHT work but it will look awful

Comment: Thanks for the response , please let me know if got any other solutions